# Installing openTSDB on Ubuntu15.04

Tags: service, deb, opentsdb, ubuntu-15.04

I have installed openTSDB[(.deb package)](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/installation.html#debian-package) on ubuntu 15.04 by following the guidelines stated in documentation. when I give this command "service opentsdb start" it is not starting and it is mentioned in documentation that we have to change some configuration files.can anyone please tell me what are the changes that we have to do and in which file the changes have to be done?

Thanks in advance

Regards
VHC

Comment: It says, in the documentation you linked to, that "The Debian package will create the following directories: /etc/opentsdb - Configuration files".  Did you look in there?

Comment: All those were created.But if you see they also mentioned it will not start automatically for the first time and changes need to be made to config files to make it run. Also I would like to know is it mandatory to install Zookeeper first before installing TSDB? i dont have zookeeper installed

Comment: You need to have ZooKeeper running somewhere and point OpenTSDB to it.  ZooKeeper doesn't have to be on the same host.  The default config works if ZooKeeper and HBase are all on the same host, because it uses localhost by default for most things, but otherwise you have to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs in /var/log/opentsdb/opentsdb.log. You should have HBase up&running correctly (means i.e. you are able to create table and store some values)

Remember you have to create tables in HBase running

```
env COMPRESSION=NONE HBASE_HOME=path/to/hbase-X.XX.X /usr/share/opentsdb/tools/create_table.sh
```

http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/installation.html#create-tables